# Undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass, help reconfigure the controller to make it work without already created pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @item = Page.find_by_slug!(params[:children].try(:split, '/').try(:last) || params[:slug])
    render @item.view_name || 'simple'
  end

  def table
  end
end
```

it log

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 101ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass):
51:           </ul>
52:         </nav>
53:         <a href="callto:800203233" class="phone right20">800 203 233</a>
54:         <% if Page.pages_by_menu(:top).any? %>
55:         <nav class="navigation right20">
56:           <ul class="list-unstyled">
57:             <% Page.pages_by_menu(:top).published.each do |page| %>

app/models/page.rb:84:in `pages_by_menu'
app/views/partials/home/_header.html.erb:54:
    in     `_app_views_partials_home__header_html_erb__244943096006790635_61272040'
app/views/layouts/home.html.erb:30:
    in `_app_views_layouts_home_html_erb___3961837791784132882_66047860'
```

It model page.rb(sorry but post is mostly code, then I зart of porridge

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FinderSlug

  attr_reader :meta
  attr_accessor :toggles, :gallery_images

  belongs_to :snippet
  belongs_to :manager
  has_many :page_toggles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :gallery_items, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true

  mount_uploader :image, PageImageUploader

  has_ancestry
  acts_as_list scope: [:ancestry]
  enum position_type: [:bottom, :top]
  scope :published, ->{ where(published: true) }

  before_save :generate_slug
  after_save :add_gallery_items

  def add_gallery_items
    GalleryItem.transaction do
      return if self.gallery_images.nil?
      self.gallery_images.each do |item|
        self.gallery_items.create(image: item[:image])
      end
    end
  end

  def add_toggles
    PageToggle.transaction do
      self.page_toggles.destroy_all unless self.new_record?
      return if self.toggles.nil?
      self.toggles.each do |toggle|
        self.page_toggles.create(title: toggle[:title], content: toggle[:content])
      end
    end
  end

  def unique_page_record
    self.children.where(title: self.title).try(:first) || self
  end

  def generate_slug
    self.slug = self.title.to_url 
    self.slug += '-root' if persisted? && self.children.exists?(title: self.title)
  end

  def core_page?
    %w().include? self.id.to_s
  end

  def hidden_content_area?
    %w().include? self.id.to_s
  end

  def type_page
    if self.core_page?
      (!self.published?) ? 'hidden_core' : 'core'
    elsif !self.published?
      'hidden'
    elsif self.position_type.present?
      'menu'
    elsif self.root?
      'root'
    else
      'default'
    end
  end

  def page_path
    paths = []
    paths += ancestors.where(position_type: nil).select(:slug, :custom_slug).map(&:once_slug) if depth > 0
    paths.push self.once_slug
    "/#{paths.join('/')}"
  end

  class << self
    def pages_by_menu(menu)
      find_by(position_type: self.position_types[menu]).children.published.order(:position)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The error happenned in `app/models/page.rb:84`, so please show your model file.

Comment: I add model, sorry for  part of porridge

Comment: It's saying there's a problem when it calls `pages_by_menu`, in that it tries to call `#children` on `nil`. If you look at `pages_by_menu` you can see that it calls `#children` on the result of `find_by(position_type: self.position_types[menu])`. [`find_by` returns nil when no record is found](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by).

Comment: So how was looking code?

Comment: make sure that you have pages that fulfil this: `position_type: :top`

Comment: I need somy check if the page is nil that return pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply handle the error (avoid triggering the exception), you can do it like this:

```
class << self
  def pages_by_menu(menu)
    pages = find_by(position_type: self.position_types[menu])
    pages.nil? ? [] : pages.children.published.order(:position)
  end
end
```

Comment: New ERRORActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `published' for []:Array):
    1: <footer class="footer">
    2:   <div class="container">
    3:     <div class="row">
    4:       <% if Page.pages_by_menu(:bottom).published.any? %>
    5:           <% Page.pages_by_menu(:bottom).published.each do |page| %>

Comment: what is `children` I do not see it defined as an association or a method of the Page model.

Comment: this will probably work: `pages.published.order(:position)` but I am not sure if that is what you need...